# Java while 2 conditions

Tags: java, while-loop

I need to have something like this, but now sure if possible:

- a `while` with 2 conditions and when first condition is `false` I do not want the second condition to be considered, so I want the `while` to not be executed.
  The second condition I need to be evaluated only when the first one is true.

thanks

UPDATE
I think I wasn't clear enough with this question... I've tried to simplify as much as possible... in fact is something related to threads; i know about && operator; It will be better if this question will be deleted...thanks

Comment: I wish you had tried something and posted the same.

Comment: I didn't made myself clear enough... the problem in fact is more complicated.. i've tried to simplify it and seems that I failed in doing this :D

Answer (score 4):

```
while (firstCondation && secondCondition) {
   ...
}
```

with the && operator the second condition will evalue only if the first one is true.

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` operator is 'lazy' so the second argument (condition2) is only evaluated in the case that condition1 evaluates to True. So using the following code would help you:

```
while( condition1 && condition2 ) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(condition1 && condidtion2) {
   //do stuff
}
```

By using the `and` operator it will only execute while both conditions are true.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a **short-circuit AND operator**.

The `&&` is a short-circuit  operator in Java. You can use it in while loop as follows:

```
while(condition1 && condition2)
{

}
```

This means that if `condition1` is `true`, only then `condition2` will be evaluated. If `condition1` is `false`, then the `while` loop will exit.